# poner el texto al lado de una imagen

Tags: css, reactjs

Tengo un problema con css y es que estoy haciendo los detalles de mi pregunto, por lo que quiero que me quede la imagen a la izquierda y el nombre, precio y descripcion a la derecha. Lo que hice fue meter todo en un div y agregarle display flex. Si bien se ponen a la derecha de la imagen, los textos no ocupan todo el espacio vacio, por ejemplo: quiero que diga "Lona milan" y que milan quede al lado de lona pero lo que sucede es que queda "Lona" y debajo "milan". Con el precio lo mismo, me queda el signo $ arriba y los numero debajo. Probe con propiedades float pero nada. Muestro el codigo (es React, jsx por eso dice className)

```
    <div className='detail'>
        <div className='detail-container'>
        <img src={image} alt='producto' />
        <h2>{name}</h2>
        <p className='detail-price'>$ {price}</p>
        <p className='detail-description'>{description}</p>
        </div>
          <div  className='box-count'>
           <ItemCount stock={stock} amounts={takeAmount}/>
           <div className='box-count-onadd'>
            <button onClick={onAdd}>Agregar al carrito</button>
           </div>
          </div>
    </div>


    .detail img{
max-width: 60%;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .detail h2{
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: 5%;
margin-left: 5%;
    }


    .detail-container{
display: flex;
    }

    .detail-description{
margin-top: 20%;
    }

    .detail-price{
margin-top: 15%;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo agregaría una etiqueta div que contenga el nombre el precio y la descripción, donde usaria flexbox.

```
  <div className='detail-container'>
    <img src="logo192.png" alt='producto' />
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
      <h2>{name}</h2>
      <p className='detail-price'>$ {price}</p>
      <p className='detail-description'>{description}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

También agregaría mas estilos al .detail-container:

```
.detail-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder! tampoco funciono, lo hice tal cual solo que saque el justify content y el align items del detail-container porque quedaba la imagen en el medio. Con lo que me recomendaste que hagame queda la imagen a la izquierda y lo demas debajo, pero no a la derecha.